# Why flask app is stopping suddenly when doing gill pull using threading module

Tags: python, flask

I am facing some issues while running my flask loop along with another thread loop called git_pull to do a git pull every two hours against git repos.

My flask loop stops when there are any conflicts and other issues while doing the git pull using the thread loop.

some times my flask loops run without any issues for days but suddenly stop when there are any conflicts with the git pull and unknown issues with the git pull

I am not getting any idea to avoid those errors to not disturb my flask loop

even if git pull is having some errors it should not disturb my flask loop and then run continuously.

and the next cycle of threading that git pull happens without any issues( I observed this )

here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response, Response
from constants import constants, git_pull_thread
import threading

# logs
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

hunter = Flask(__name__)
health_status = True

def main():
    # pre tasks for git repos called policy, e2policy
    git_pull_thread()

    # main loop
    try:
        logger.info("hunter service is running ")
        threading.Thread(target=hunter.run(ssl_context=(constants.CLIENT_CERT_PATH, constants.CLIENT_KEY_PATH),
                                           host='0.0.0.0',
                                           port=5002,
                                           debug=True)).start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"[-] Exception encountered while running the flask mode : {e}")

# main loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have another file called constants.py

```
import os
import subprocess
import threading

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

GIT_PULL_INTERVAL = 7200  # 2 hours in seconds

def pre_tasks():
     
     while True:
        Directory = ["/hunter/tmp/policy","/hunter/tmp/e2policy"]              
        for dir in Directory:
             logging.info("#####" + dir + "repo is updating #####")
             cmd = "git pull "
             process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=dir)
             output = process.communicate()[0]
             sleep(120)
             logging.info(output)
        sleep(GIT_PULL_INTERVAL)

def git_pull_thread():
    """
    it keeps on doing the git pull for git repos
    """
    try:
        logger.info("Threading loop started ")
        threading.Thread(target=pre_tasks).start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"[-] Exception encountered while performing the pre tasks: {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to make sure that the Flask loop runs continuously even if there are errors during the `git pull` process. To achieve this, you can add exception handling within the `pre_tasks` function in `constants.py` to catch any errors that occur during the `git pull` process.

Here's a modified version of your `constants.py` file:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import threading
import logging
from time import sleep

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

GIT_PULL_INTERVAL = 7200  # 2 hours in seconds

def pre_tasks():
    while True:
        Directory = ["/hunter/tmp/policy","/hunter/tmp/e2policy"]              
        for dir in Directory:
            try:
                logging.info("#####" + dir + "repo is updating #####")
                cmd = "git pull "
                process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=dir)
                output = process.communicate()[0]
                sleep(120)
                logging.info(output)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"[-] Exception encountered while updating the repo {dir}: {e}")
        sleep(GIT_PULL_INTERVAL)

def git_pull_thread():
    """
    it keeps on doing the git pull for git repos
    """
    try:
        logger.info("Threading loop started ")
        threading.Thread(target=pre_tasks).start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"[-] Exception encountered while performing the pre tasks: {e}")
```

This should prevent errors from the `git pull` process from affecting your Flask loop. If an error occurs during a `git pull`, it will be caught, logged, and the loop will continue with the next directory or the next iteration.

Also, in your main file, you should start the Flask loop and the `git_pull_thread()` in separate threads. Modify the `main()` function like this:

```py
def main():
    # pre tasks for git repos called policy, e2policy
    git_pull_thread()

    # main loop
    try:
        logger.info("hunter service is running ")
        threading.Thread(target=hunter.run, kwargs={
            'ssl_context': (constants.CLIENT_CERT_PATH, constants.CLIENT_KEY_PATH),
            'host': '0.0.0.0',
            'port': 5002,
            'debug': True}).start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"[-] Exception encountered while running the flask mode : {e}")
```

This modification ensures that the Flask loop and the `git_pull_thread()` are running in separate threads and do not block each other.

Comment: THank you @frank 

when i run the code as per your suggestions I am getting below error

Comment: I am getting below error whille running code by your changes.

2023-03-16 17:12:38     signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *args: sys.exit(0))
2023-03-16 17:12:38   File "/opt/sfdc/python39/lib/python3.9/signal.py", line 56, in signal
2023-03-16 17:12:38     handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
2023-03-16 17:12:38 ValueError: signal only works in the main thread of the main interpreter

Comment: 6 17:12:38 ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
2023-03-16 17:12:52 From https://git.soma.salesforce.com/netsec/netpolicy
2023-03-16 17:12:52    eed84eb..6a08b05  master     -> origin/master
2023-03-16 17:12:52    018ba1c..8aba935  corp_pan   -> origin/corp_pan
2023-03-16 17:12:52    80ae84d..bf1e93e  cross-site1 -> origin/cross-site1
2023-03-16 17:12:52    47a0a61..69294f0  cross-site2 -> origin/cross-site2
2023-03-16 17:12:52    c57197b..9358ec0  cross-site3 -> origin/cross-site3
2023-03-16 17:12:52    507f111..ad2a7a3  cross-site4 -> origin/cross-site4